# Array list is shown, array length is 0 and elements are undefined in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise

So, basically i have two api calls in two different functions that are called from a single component page. The await function is applied to each of them because each of the response provided from the first api is used as params to the second api. for the first api call, inside the function, the response is pushed to the array named all_countries.

```
const apiCall = getCountry(req)
      .then((response) => {
        all_countries.push(...response);
        dispatch(actionSuccess(NICE_ONE, response));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(actionFailure(NICE_ONE, error));
      });
```

each of the array objects inside all_countries is to be mapped and value(i.e country code present inside each object from all_countries) is used to call another api to get the response but my problem is upon console logging the all_countries from the second function, it shows the symbol of empty array. upon opening the array, it lists all the countries. when i console log the length of the array, it shows 0 and upon console logging the elements like all_countries[0], it shows undefined. Why is this happening? Could someone help me out please?
[This gets shown on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOBNd.png)

Upon expanding, this is shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhpdd.png)

So, i found that on adding all_countries.push, intellij shows me a warning, response is not an array type but rather AllCountryRes type.

AllRelaysRes type is defined as:

```
export type AllRelaysRes = {
  logo: string;
  ipv4: string;
  ipv6: string;
  port: string;
  location: {
    id: number;
    ip: string
  };
};
```

and the getCountry function is like this:

```
export const getCountry = (url: string): Promise<AllRelaysRes> => {
  ExternalApi.setBaseUrl(url);
  return ExternalApi.apiCall<AllRelaysRes>({
    method: "GET",
    url: "something",
  });
};
```

The response from the api is an array of objects. I am just a beginner with typescript and trying out stuffs. My question is how do i make the response type as an array of object AllRelayRes? Doesnot return ExternalApi.apiCall angular brackets AllRelayRes mean that the response expected is an array of AllRelayRes since, AllRelayRes is kept inside the angular brackets? How do i fix this? Is this the real problem why i get the array length 0?

Comment: can we see the console.log you're talking about? It sounds like it's returning an object, not array?

Comment: I have added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: Can you give us a codesandbox to interact with?

Comment: Sorry, i can't. I would have already posted the code if i could, but i guess i found out the problem. On pushing the data to all_countries, it says "response" is not an array type. I am figuring out the way to declaring type of response as an array of object.

Comment: I added the code if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're dealing with a collection of objects of type `AllRelayRes`, not an array. It shows as `[]` in the console, but that represents a collection.

If you want to use it as an array, specify the type in your function `<AllRelaysRes[]>`

```
export const getCountry = (url: string): Promise<AllRelaysRes[]> => {
  ExternalApi.setBaseUrl(url);
  return ExternalApi.apiCall<AllRelaysRes[]>({
    method: "GET",
    url: "something",
  });
};
```

Then you should be able to manipulate the data in an array format

If you want to keep it as a collection, you can probably iterate through them with

```
let x, key, obj
for(x in AllRelayRes) {
    key = x; // 0, 1, 2 .. the index
    obj = AllRelayRex[x] // the object
    // country_name = AllRelayRex[x].country_name, etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. can I ask you something? The response from the above data contains a list of codes, and I need each of the codes as params to fetch other requests which contains details of items. for now, i have used .then and called the other function to fetch the details passing the each of the codes. Is there a better approach to it?

Comment: @Nothing - sorry, it's hard to advise without having a better grasp of the architecture here. Try your idea and if you run into performance issues start up another question.